# Why is $\frac{\partial n}{\partial v}$ in the tangent plane?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I got a ruled surface $f(u,v) = c(u)+v\cdot X(u)$.

I first calculated the partial derivatives...

\begin{align*}
f_u = c'(u)+vX'(u),\quad f_v = X(u),\quad f_{uu} = c''(u)+vX''(u),\quad f_{uv} = X'(u),\quad  f_{vv} = 0
\end{align*}

According to the solutions, I need to look at the normal vector $n=\frac{f_u \times f_v}{\| f_u \times f_v\|}$ and notice following...

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\langle n,f_u \rangle=\langle \frac{\partial n}{\partial v},f_u \rangle + \langle n, X'\rangle =0\Rightarrow -\langle \frac{\partial n}{\partial v},f_u \rangle = \langle n, X'\rangle
\end{align*}

The solutions then say that for $\frac{\partial n}{\partial v}\neq 0$ we see that $\frac{\partial n}{\partial v}$, $f_u$ and $f_v$ lie in the tangent plane and are linear dependent.

But I don't really see how that's obvious. Can someone explain?

EDIT for Context:

[image]

Comment: Which step are you concerned with: The deduction to $-\langle \partial n/\partial v, f_u\rangle=\langle n,X'(u)\rangle$, or the implication that this means $\partial n/\partial v,f_u,f_v$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: This does not seem correct to me. What are we trying to prove?

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm concerned about the implication that these results are lineraly dependent and are in the tangent plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin We're trying to prove that $\frac{\partial n}{\partial v} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow K = 0$ where $K$ is the gaussian curvature.

Comment: That statement is independent of any computation here. If the normal is constant along the rulings, $0$ is an eigenvalue of the shape operator. But this is not true for every ruled surface!!

Comment: Do you have a source for this problem?

Comment: @Semiclassical I've added context. Unfortunately it's in german but only a few words. "in der Tangentialebene, also linear abhängig" means "in tangent plane, therefore linearly dependent".

Comment: Note that the partial derivatives of $\nu$ are always in the tangent plane (why?), so the linear dependence is automatic and has nothing to do with these calculations.